# Multiple If Statements Indentation Error?

Tags: vba, if-statement, indentation

So, I think I am doing something wrong but need a little guidance.

Below Code is supposed a calculation one way based on a combobox "Awarding" result. Currently my calculation is doing the calculation incorrectly (as it is thinking it is "both halfs same term"). I believe this is due to my indentation or incorrect use of multiple nested if statements.

```
 If Awarding = "First Half All Credits in One Half" Or Awarding = "Second Half Only" Then
     If LEU.Value <> "" And PLEU < CalcElig Then
         Payment1.Value = PLEU
     If PAmtUnused < CalcElig Then
         Payment1.Value = PAmtUnused
     Else: Payment1.Value = Payment1.Value = Round(CLng(PSchAward) *      PTotalAyWeeks / PMinAyWeeks / 2, 0)
     End If

     PPayment1 = Payment1.Value
     PPayment2 = 0
     TotalPayment = PPayment1 + PPayment2
     End If
 End If


 If Awarding = "Both Halfs Same Term" Then
     If LEU.Value <> "" And PLEU < CalcEligA Then
         Payment1.Value = PLEU
     ElseIf PAmtUnused < CalcEligA Then
         Payment1.Value = PAmtUnused
     Else: Payment1.Value = CalcEligA
     End If


     PPayment1 = Payment1.Value


     If LEU.Value <> "" And PLEU > 0 Then
         Payment2.Value = PLEU - PPayment1
     Else: Payment2.Value = CalcEligB
     End If

     If PAmtUnused - PPayment1 < PLEU - PPayment1 Then
         Payment2.Value = PAmtUnused - PPayment1
     ElseIf PAmtUnused - PPayment1 < CalcEligB Then
         Payment2.Value = PAmtUnused - PPayment1
     Else: Payment2.Value = CalcEligB
     End If


     PPayment2 = Payment2.Value

     TotalPayment = PPayment1 + PPayment2

     End If

 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Indentation doesn't matter to the compiler, it's just for the benefit of humans.

Comment: Alright I for some reason thought indentation mattered? Then mind schooling me on my obvious oversight then?

Comment: If you have programmed in Python then you might have internalized the notion that indentation matters. In principle it doesn't matter in VBA -- though white space in the form of newlines does matter as a statement terminator. Nevertheless -- consistent indentation is an overwhelmingly good idea, even if no one but you is likely to read the code since among other things it is a major aid in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your first block.

Your code (with added indentations to show the flow):

```
If Awarding = "First Half All Credits in One Half" Or Awarding = "Second Half Only" Then
     If LEU.Value <> "" And PLEU < CalcElig Then
         Payment1.Value = PLEU
         If PAmtUnused < CalcElig Then
            'This will write over Payment1.Value if both If conditions are satisfied.
             Payment1.Value = PAmtUnused
         Else: Payment1.Value = Payment1.Value = Round(CLng(PSchAward) *      PTotalAyWeeks / PMinAyWeeks / 2, 0)
      'The else condition will write over Payment1.Value if the second If condition is not satisfied.
         End If
'Payment1.Value is NEVER set if the first IF statement evaluates to FALSE,
' and it is written over if the first IF statement evaluates to TRUE!!
         PPayment1 = Payment1.Value
         PPayment2 = 0
         TotalPayment = PPayment1 + PPayment2
     End If
End If
```

What you probably meant (due to the other blocks):

```
If Awarding = "First Half All Credits in One Half" Or Awarding = "Second Half Only" Then
    If LEU.Value <> "" And PLEU < CalcElig Then
        Payment1.Value = PLEU
    ElseIf PAmtUnused < CalcElig Then
        Payment1.Value = PAmtUnused
    Else: Payment1.Value = Payment1.Value = Round(CLng(PSchAward) *      PTotalAyWeeks / PMinAyWeeks / 2, 0)
    End If

    PPayment1 = Payment1.Value
    PPayment2 = 0
    TotalPayment = PPayment1 + PPayment2

End If
```

There is also an additional problem.

This line of code:

```
Else: Payment1.Value = Payment1.Value = Round(CLng(PSchAward) *      PTotalAyWeeks / PMinAyWeeks / 2, 0)
```

is going to put either TRUE or FALSE in Payment1.  It is the same as:

```
 Else: Payment1.Value = (Payment1.Value = Round(CLng(PSchAward) *      PTotalAyWeeks / PMinAyWeeks / 2, 0))
```

where the portion in parentheses is evaluated as to whether the two values on either side of the equals sign are equal.

You probably meant to only have one equality:

```
Else: Payment1.Value = Round(CLng(PSchAward) *      PTotalAyWeeks / PMinAyWeeks / 2, 0)
```

The best way to figure out errors like this is to step through the code and see what exactly is happening and how the program is running through the code compared to what you expect.

Comment: thanks for pointing out all of the syntax errors. The main issue is still that the end of the code where " If Awarding = "Both Halfs Same Term" " occurs is the final output of the user form when i have "Awarding = "First Half All Credits in One Half" Or Awarding = "Second Half Only" "

Comment: What does that mean?  The "final output of the user form"?  What line of code is producing this output?  What line is causing it to go on the user form?  What inputs are you giving (in terms of the variable Awarding), and what exactly is happening as a result of this input?  After stepping through the code, how is the program being executed?

Comment: Additionally, if the fixes I provided are resulting in the same problem, then I would update the question to include the code with the fixed syntax and then explain what the problem is including the answers to the questions I've posed in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Even though OpiesDad was a great help it turns out there was some REALLY bad syntax issues. I had to retool the whole thing to be less cluttered and to make more sense. The solution is INF different than the original post but I wanted to make to post a response.

Main point of contention:

```
Trying to separate calculations 
Multiple static value declarations
Being dumb
```